# Proof that $e^n$ can not be expressed as a weighted sum of other powers of $e$

Tags: exponential-function

How can I prove that 
$$e^n \neq \sum_{i=0, i\neq n }^{+\infty}k_ie^{i} $$
where e is the base of the natural logarithm, $k_i$ are non-negative integers, and $n$ is a positive integer?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That's what I thought initially, but I'm not sure how to rule out the case that the sum goes infinitely to the left.

Comment: I made a mistake in the statement, there is no infinite sum to the left, it starts at zero. Still it is not clear to me how to prove it.

Comment: @Sunny88 Suppose you had such an expression.  Then $e$ is the root of a polynomial with rational coefficients.  But $e$ cannot be the root of a polynomial with rational coefficients (because it is transcendental).

Comment: @Sunny88: I deleted my comment after reading that, but actually that was unnecessary: in order for this sum to converge it must be finite, since otherwise it fails the limit test. So we are back to transcendentality.